# XML file auto formatted with newlines

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file with no return spaces entered. Is there a program out there that can automatically format the xml file with return spaces and indentations so the xml file is more readable and I do not have to go through and hit enter a million times? If so, how do you use it? Currently I am viewing the file in Notepad++ and cannot find any option to do this for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I went to "Plugins" then "Plugin Manager" then "Show Plugin Manager" and browsed for XML tools. I then followed the directions from this link. http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/813349/thread/77255855 which says go to Plugins, XML tools, Pretty Print XML only with line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse IDE, you can do ctrl+shift+f, which will format your code, or xml file, to the default formatting.  I'm not sure about Notepad++.